# Consumer acting oddly in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm just getting back into Kotlin (transitioning from java) and I've noticed that using a `Consumer` is trickier than it sounds.

```
class EventBus(controller: Controller) {
    private val consumerMap : MutableMap<KClass<out Event>, MutableSet<Consumer<out Event>>> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    private val controller : Controller = controller

    public fun <T : Event> register(clazz: KClass<T>, handler: Consumer<T>) {
        consumerMap.getOrPut(clazz, { HashSet() }).add(handler)
    }

    public fun <T : Event> post(event : T) {
        consumerMap[event.javaClass.kotlin]?.forEachIndexed { i, handler ->
            controller.getLogger().trace("Firing handler ${i + 1} for event ${event.javaClass.name}")
            handler.accept(event)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to make a simple class for firing dead basic events, the only problem is according to IntelliJ the accept method does not exist. However, when I attempt to create a new consumer and use it straight away the accept method is there and works just as expected.

http://pksv.co/go/myOeEvTE

Is there anything I may have missed or overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silly me. I've had java drilled into my head for so long. Replacing the `Consumer<out Event>` (and other `Consumer` uses) with `(Event) -> Unit` cleared up everything!

For anyone interested in the code:

```
class EventBus(controller: Controller) {
    private val consumerMap : MutableMap<KClass<out Event>, MutableSet<(Event) -> Unit>> = ConcurrentHashMap()
    private val controller : Controller = controller

    public fun <T : Event> register(clazz: KClass<T>, handler: (T) -> Unit) {
        consumerMap.getOrPut(clazz, { HashSet() }).add(handler as (Event) -> Unit) // hacky cast :-)
    }

    public fun <T : Event> post(event : T) {
        consumerMap[event.javaClass.kotlin]?.forEachIndexed { i, handler ->
            controller.getLogger().trace("Firing handler ${i + 1} for event ${event.javaClass.name}")
            handler.invoke(event)
        }
    }
}
```